# I'm trying to write a format string in c (command line tool)

Tags: c

So what I'm trying to do specifically is write code that tells me the sine of one radian, which is 0.841.

When I write my code, I get 0.000. 
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include < math.h>
#include < stdlib.h>
int main(...[] ). {
    double sin (double x) ;
    printf(" radian = %.3f sin.\n", "double sin");
. . .
```

My output is :

```
Radian = 0.000 sin
```

Comment: `"double sin"` is a string. Try `sin(1)` (if `sin` takes radians).

Comment: ...and use a proper editor. New lines don't start with a capital! (as Uri Brecher edied)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Passing `const char*` to `%f` in `printf()`, which calls for `double`, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   double sinVal = sin( 1.0 );
   printf( "radian=%.3f sin\n", sinVal );
}
```

which produces

```
radian=0.841 sin
```